# How to offset Pie Menu slots/sub-menus for compound menus to not overlap

Tags: python, interface, add-on, pie-menu

I'm working with a gigantic pie menu, i need to carefully fit every Pie UI slot so that they don't overlap, the issue is that scaling or not, the Pie slot auto aligns to an invisible center

as seen in the picture I'm trying to add a new section to the left (slot 1) but i cannot find a variable for offset in PieUI.box(), and i can't find a UI element that is invisible to which i can add a spacer to not block visibility of the other menus

is there a way to offset the Layout.pie_menu() slots? or is there a way to add an invisible box container to which i can add a spacer?

i cannot provide the full code and it's also not relevant 
example container code for the top menu:

```
AlxLayout = self.layout
PieUI = AlxLayout.menu_pie()

TBoxMenuSpace = PieUI.box().row()
TBoxMenuSectionL = TBoxMenuSpace.box()
TBoxMenuSectionL.ui_units_x = 10.0
TBoxMenuSectionL.ui_units_y = 10.0
TBoxMenuSectionM = TBoxMenuSpace.box()
TBoxMenuSectionM.ui_units_x = 12.0
TBoxMenuSectionM.ui_units_y = 10.0
TBoxMenuSectionR = TBoxMenuSpace.box()
TBoxMenuSectionR.ui_units_x = 10.0
TBoxMenuSectionR.ui_units_y = 10.0
```

[image: Current Pie Menu with no offset]